# Memory allocation and life of variables

Tags: java

My question or rather questions are as follows:

1)Where does the static variable reside . Some articles say they reside on the heap and some some say in the perm gen area with the class definition as they are class attributes. I understand the second option might be correct because it is a class attribute.
2)Where does the final variable reside and what is its life if:
   a) Its an instance variable of type primitive
   b) Its a local variable of a method of type primitive
   c) Its an instance variable of type reference
   b) Its a local variable of a method of type reference
3)Where are the reference local variables stored if they are local.
4)In case of arrays is there any difference in memory allocation as in they are instance variable or local thread variable.

Thanks

Comment: How about 4 different threads for 4 different questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Where does the static variable reside`

**-** static variable resides in `Method Area`, and permgen is inside Method area.

```
Where does the final variable reside and what is its life if
Its an instance variable of type primitive
```

**-** If its instance variable, it stays on the `Heap inside the Object` to which it belongs, and falls out of scope as there is no reference to the Object which holds it..

`Its a local variable of a method of type primitive`

**-** It stays on the Stack, and and falls out of scope as there as the methods closing brace is reached...

`Its an instance variable of type reference`

**-** it stays on the `Heap inside the Object` to which it belongs, and falls out of scope as there is no reference to the Object which holds it..

`Its a local variable of a method of type reference`

**-** It stays on the Stack, and and falls out of scope as there as the methods closing brace is reached...

`Where are the reference local variables stored if they are local.`

**-** On the Stack...

`In case of arrays is there any difference in memory allocation as in they are instance` `variable or local thread variable.`

**-** Well as **Array is an object** it is stored on `Heap`....but from `Java 6u23` version, there has been the introduction of `Escape Analysis`, according to this if the **JVM decides that the Object canNot escape the Method, it will try creating the Object on the Thread's Stack , NOT ON HEAP....**

Comment: Thanks a lot ..dat was of great great help